# How to reverse each word of a string based on the input digit given?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Following are the rules which must be followed by the program:

1. Every word in the `string` must be divided upto `n` letters each and reverse them from the start
2. Only those words must be reversed which are having length equal or greater than `n`

For example, if `string = "law of attraction"` and input `n = 3`.
Here, the length of **of** is less than `n`, thus must not be reversed, but **law** and **attraction** are having length greater than or equal to 3 thus must be reversed as

`law as wal` and
`attraction as ttacaroitn`

Final output: **wal of ttacaroitn**

In my given code, i can only able to reverse the string, but not words based on the input digit. Not getting any idea.

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Enter String: "+str);
    
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Digit = sc.nextInt();
    
    int count = str.split("\\s+").length;
    System.out.println("No.of words: "+count);
    System.out.println("Given string: "+str);
    if(Digit<=count) {
        String s[] = str.split(" ");
        String ans = "";
        for (String part : str.split(" ")) {
            System.out.print(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }   
    else {
        System.out.println("Your input Digit is Greater than count of words.");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The method **reverseSubString**  will split the word after every `n` characters.  It is then reversed.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String line = "law of attraction";
  int n = 3;
  String[] words = line.split(" ");
  for(String word: words){
    if(word.length()>=n){
      System.out.print(reverseSubString(word, n)+" ");
    } else {
      System.out.print(word + " ");
    }
  }
}

public static String reverseSubString(String s, int n) {
  String ans = "";
  String[] substrings = s.split("(?<=\\G.{"+n+"})");
  for(String substring : substrings){
    if(substring.length()==n)
       ans += new StringBuffer(substring).reverse().toString();
    else
       ans += substring;
  }
  return ans;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

`wal of ttacaroitn`

Comment: Thank you so much @Ridwan. But can you please explain s.split("(?<=\\G.{"+n+"})")

Comment: @SravanJabbala , it is a regex that matches an empty string that has **last match** (`\G`) followed by the **input digit** (`n`) **before** it (`(?<= )`)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `if(Digit<=count)` which means if n is less than the number of words then reverse all words in the loop which is the problem.

```
   if(Digit<=count) {
        String s[] = str.split(" ");
        String ans = "";
        for (String part : str.split(" ")) {
            System.out.print(new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString());
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
```

You should check with the length of every word after splitting inside loop and do the reverse when greater than or equal to n.

```
    String s[] = str.split(" ");
    for (String part : s) {
        // here to check
        if(part.size() >= Digit){
            part = new StringBuilder(part).reverse().toString();
        }
        System.out.print(part);
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
```